# log4net Temporarily Disable Debug Logging Within a Thread

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a multi-threaded app, in which I want to temporarily turn off Debug logging w/in a specific thread while it does some logging-clogging work, w/o impacting other threads.  Can this be done?

Our classes retrieve their loggers via

```
private static readonly ILog Logger = LoggerUtil.GetLogger();

public static class LoggerUtil
{
    public static ILog GetLogger()
    {
        var type = ReflectionUtil.GetCallingMethod().DeclaringType;
        return LogManager.GetLogger(type);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: For now, I created a Decorator around LogManager.GetLogger(type).Logger and a ThreadStatic IsDebugEnabled variable.  This way two threads can leverage the same utility class, and one will debug and one will not.  This is problematic because it messes with Calling Class and Line Number...

```
    public void Debug(object message)
    {
        if (_decorated.IsDebugEnabled && LoggerUtil.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            _decorated.Log(typeof (MyLoggerDecorator), Level.Debug, message, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Natively, you can't disable it by thread. You can set specifications per logger in your config. If you know your multi-threaded code always uses 1 logger (that is not shared) then you can specify to ignore that logger completely or not log debug. Other options are difficult to give w/o seeing the structure of your code. The only other option I can think of is to create your own wrapper or interceptor around the call and add the ability to suspend messages and resume them based on a thread id or other context.

Comment: If you have one logger by thread - by say adding the threadId to the logger name - then you can change the log level of that particular appender. You would need to change it back again, though, as the logger would be reused when the threadId was reused.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own custom `IFilter` implementation which looked at a `ThreadStatic` variable.

(I'd probably also create an IDisposable implementation that sets the variable to true in the constructor and sets it back to false in the `Dispose()` method, so you wrap your code in a `using` block with that, so you re-enable it automatically when you pop out of that `using` context, e.g. if there's an exception.)